# i want to build datagirdviewcomboboxcell dynamically

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I want to build a `DataGridView`, which if I choose one of the item of a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`, then the other cells in the same row which should be `TextBoxes` in other rows will turn into `ComboBoxes`,does anyone knows how to do that?

It is like:

```
TextBox1|TextBox2|ComboBox1.Item1|TextBox3 |TextBox4 |TextBox5 |TextBox6
TextBox1|TextBox2|ComboBox1.Item3|TextBox3 |TextBox4 |TextBox5 |TextBox6
TextBox1|TextBox2|ComboBox1.Item2|ComboBox3|ComboBox4|ComboBox5|ComboBox6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something when the `Value` in a `DataGridViewCell` changes then you should handle the `CellValueChanged` event of the grid.

If you want to place a cell of a specific type in a specific location in a `DataGridView` then you can do so using the grid's indexer, e.g.

```
myDataGridView[columnIndex, rowIndex] = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
```

In summary, handle the `CellValueChanged` event, use an `if` statement to test whether the `Value` is one that corresponds to a text box or combo box and, if the types of the other cells are not what they should be, replace them.